# Quarkus: Duplicate entries inside the list<Course> of the same Entity object

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, jpa, quarkus

I am currently working on a school project that allows the user to add audio courses to their library and listen to the lessons of each Course. I'll try to explain the problem with an example:

When I create a new course entity with my POST-Request, there are no lessons added in yet.
After I created the course, I add lessons to the course also via POST-Request.
So, my database (PostgreSQL) would have one entry in the course table, two entries in the lesson table
and a reference table to connect those two (hibernate generated)

The problem comes when I try to add the course to the user. It doesn't throw a warning or expectation when it adds the course and the result after the merge of the user also delivers the expected result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 674
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "courses": [
    {
      "description": "A memoir by the creator of NIKE",
      "id": 2,
      "lessons": [
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TutorialNr2"
        },
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 2,
          "name": "TutorialNr1"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Shoe Dog - Phil Knight",
      "pictureUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556906781-9a412961c28c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"
    }
  ],
  "email": "jane@doe.co",
  "id": 2,
  "password": "password",
  "subscriptions": [],
  "userName": "jane"
}

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 80ms; Content length: 674 bytes
```

But after I make another request to get everything of the user, I get this instead:

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "description": "A memoir by the creator of NIKE",
      "id": 2,
      "lessons": [
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TutorialNr2"
        },
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 2,
          "name": "TutorialNr1"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Shoe Dog - Phil Knight",
      "pictureUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556906781-9a412961c28c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"
    },
    {
      "description": "A memoir by the creator of NIKE",
      "id": 2,
      "lessons": [
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TutorialNr2"
        },
        {
          "audioUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
          "description": "A Tutorial on how to create your own Audally's",
          "duration": "00:12:54",
          "id": 2,
          "name": "TutorialNr1"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Shoe Dog - Phil Knight",
      "pictureUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556906781-9a412961c28c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"
    }
  ],
  "email": "jane@doe.co",
  "id": 2,
  "password": "password",
  "subscriptions": [],
  "userName": "jane"
}

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 50ms; Content length: 1247 bytes
```

It just displays the course times the number of lessons that the course has. in this case two lessons.
if I were to add another lesson then it would go on like that even though there are no multiple references of this in the database.

Here's my code that I use:

```
@Path("/courses")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
@ApplicationScoped
public class CourseResource {

    @Inject
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @GET
    public List<Course> getAll(){
        return courseRepository.findAll().list();
    }

    @POST
    public Response addCourse(Course course){
        if(courseRepository.findAll().stream().anyMatch(course1 ->
                        course1.name.equals(course.name) &&
                        course1.description.equals(course.description) &&
                        course1.lessons.equals(course.lessons))){
            return Response
                    .status(406,"Course already exists!")
                    .build();
        }
        Course entry = new Course();
        entry.copyProperties(course);
        courseRepository.persist(entry);
        return Response.ok(entry).build();
    }
}
```

```
@Path("/lessons")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
@ApplicationScoped
public class LessonResource {
    @Inject
    LessonRepository lessonRepository;
    @Inject
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @POST
    @Path("addLessonsToCourse/{cid}")
    public Response addLessonToCourse(@PathParam("cid") Long cid,Lesson[] lessons){
        Course read = courseRepository.findById(cid);
        if(read == null)return Response.noContent().build();
        Arrays.stream(lessons)
                .forEach(l -> {
                    Lesson created = new Lesson();
                    created.copyProperties(l);
                    lessonRepository.persist(created);
                    read.addLessons(lessonRepository.findById(created.id));
                });
        courseRepository.getEntityManager().merge(read);
        return Response.ok(courseRepository.findById(cid)).build();
    }
}
```

```
package com.audally.backend.boundary;


import io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.cache.NoCache;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import com.audally.backend.control.CourseRepository;
import com.audally.backend.control.UserRepository;
import com.audally.backend.entity.Course;
import com.audally.backend.entity.User;
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONObject;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

@Path("/users")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserResource {
    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Inject
    CourseRepository courseRepository;
    @JsonbTransient
    private JSONObject businessuser;

    @GET
    @Path("/{UserId}")
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("UserId") Long uid){
        return Response.ok(userRepository.findById(uid)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{UserId}/courses")
    public Response getCoursesOfUser(@PathParam("UserId") Long uid){
        User user = userRepository.findById(uid);
        if(user == null){
            return Response
                    .status(202,"Course already exists in the User!")
                    .build();
        }
        businessuser = new JSONObject();
        businessuser.merge("courses",user.courses.stream().filter(distinctByKey(course -> course.name))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()),(o, o2) -> o = o2);
        return Response.ok(businessuser.get("courses")).build();
    }
    @POST
    @Path("{UserId}/courses/{CourseId}")
    public Response addCourseToUser(@PathParam("UserId") Long uid
            ,@PathParam("CourseId") Long cid){
        User user = userRepository.findById(uid);
        Course course = courseRepository.findById(cid);
        if(user.courses.contains(course)){
            return Response
                    .status(406,"Course already exists in the User!")
                    .build();
        }
        if(user == null){
            return Response
                    .status(204,"User was not found!")
                    .build();
        }
        else if(course == null){
            return Response
                    .status(204,"Course was not found!")
                    .build();
        }
        user.addCourses(course);
        userRepository.getEntityManager().merge(user);
        return Response.ok(userRepository.findById(uid)).build();
    }
    @POST
    @Transactional
    @Path("addUser")
    public Response addUser(User user){
        User entry = new User();
        if(userRepository.find("email",user.email).count() == 1){
            return Response
                    .status(406,"User email already exists!")
                    .build();
        }
        entry.copyProperties(user);
        userRepository.persist(entry);
        return Response.ok(entry).build();
    }

    public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(
            Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {

        Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    }
}
```

I hotfixed the problem by throwing a distinct (in the method: getCoursesOfUser) to every course that is the same in there but I just want to know if there is a better way to fix this problem?

For reference:
All Repositories implement **PanacheRepositoryBase<Enitity,Long>** and have no further code added to them.

```
package com.audally.backend.entity;


import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses",schema = "audally")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "courseSequence",
            sequenceName = "course_id_seq",
            initialValue = 4,
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
            ,generator = "courseSequence")
    public Long id;
    @NotNull
    public String name;
    @Size(max = 400)
    public String description;
    @URL
    public String pictureUrl;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Lesson> lessons = new ArrayList<Lesson>();

    public Course(){

    }
    public void addLessons(Lesson lesson){
        this.lessons.add(lesson);
    }
    public List<Lesson> getLessons(){
        return this.lessons;
    }
    public void copyProperties(Course course) {
        this.name = course.name;
        this.lessons = course.lessons;
        this.description = course.description;
        this.pictureUrl = course.pictureUrl;
    }

}
```

```
package com.audally.backend.entity;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL;

import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lessons",schema = "audally")
public class Lesson implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "lessonSequence",
            sequenceName = "lesson_id_seq",
            initialValue = 1,
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
            ,generator = "lessonSequence")
    public Long id;
    @NotNull
    public String name;
    @Size(max = 400)
    public String description;
    @URL
    public String audioUrl;
    @JsonbDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    public LocalTime duration;
    /*@ManyToOne
    @JsonbTransient
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    public Course course;
    */
    public void copyProperties(Lesson lesson) {
        this.name = lesson.name;
        this.duration = lesson.duration;
        this.audioUrl = lesson.audioUrl;
        this.description = lesson.description;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAudioUrl() {
        return audioUrl;
    }

    public void setAudioUrl(String audioUrl) {
        this.audioUrl = audioUrl;
    }

    public LocalTime getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(LocalTime duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
/*
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }*/
}
```

I had the relationship between Course and Lesson Bidirectional at first, thinking that this caused the problem, I changed it over to One-Directional, as in, Only Course knows of the lessons and the lessons
only know themselves, but this didn't solve the problem.

```
package com.audally.backend.entity;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.touri.MappedBy;

import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users",schema = "audally")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "userSequence",
            sequenceName = "user_id_seq",
            initialValue = 3,
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
            ,generator = "userSequence")
    public Long id;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Not allowed to be empty!")
    public String userName;
    @NotNull
    @Email
    public String email;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    public String password;
    /*
    @NotNull
    public Date joinDate;
    */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    public List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
    public User(){ }

    public void copyProperties(User user) {
        this.email = user.email;
        this.subscriptions = user.subscriptions;
        this.courses = user.courses;
        this.userName = user.userName;
        this.password = user.password;
    }

    public void addCourses(Course courses) {
        this.courses.add(courses);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", subscriptions=" + subscriptions.toArray().toString() +
                ", courses=" + courses.toArray().toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If there is anything that I left out or that someone would like to know, I'm happy to provide it.
I just want this weird bug? to go away and for my code to do the job it is supposed to do...

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! :) If I understood it correctly, then the basic problem is that you're doing multiple `GET` requests, but the answer is different each time -- namely the courses duplicate. Correct?

Comment: thx ^^, and not necessarily, so, when I execute get requests that load in the courses of the user, then it displays the course inside of the JSON array course times the number of Lessons that the course has. In other words. yes and no? the correct answer is displayed after the course is added to the user (The response of 
return Response.ok(userRepository.findById(uid)).build();)
but when I try to get the user it will show the duplicate courses, and if I were to Add
more lessons to the course, it would show more duplicate courses..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem with a little help from my friends.

The problem for anyone wondering was, that I was using FetchType.Eager instead of Lazy
Which resulted in the multiple Courses being shown. It probably pulled the course, each time a new lesson was added and that's how things ended up then.